# DbMigrator does not commit changes to database

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I'm trying to programmatically initialize a SQL Server database using `DbMigrator` class from `EntityFramework`:

```
var configuration = new MyDataBaseAssembly.Migrations.Configuration();  
configuration.TargetDatabase = new System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbConnectionInfo(myConnectionString, "System.Data.SqlClient");

var dbMigrator = new DbMigrator(configuration);
dbMigrator.Update();

using (var context = new MyDataBaseAssembly.MyDataBaseContext(myConnectionString))
{
    // do some queries
    context.MyTable1.ToList();
}
```

The weird thing is that the code works fine for all my database assemblies except one. For some reason one of the DB's is not getting initialized, and I'm receiving an exception:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid object name 'dbo.MyTable1'.
```

When I open the SQL Server Profiler, I can see that all the migrations are being applied with no errors. However, when I open the database in SQL Server Management Studio, I can see that it contains no tables at all.

After further investigating, I found out that after `dbMigrator.Update` is executed, the transaction it uses is not committed to the DB (`DBCC OPENTRAN` outputs that the transaction is still open). And for some reason, the transaction data gets discarded before I try to do some queries using `MyDataBaseContext`.

What can be the cause of such behavior? Why does `dbMigrator.Update` commit all the necessary migrations for some databases, but not for others? Can I control `dbMigrator` transactions manually and force them to commit?

Comment: I just ran into the same issue. When I use a MigratorScriptorDecorator it's not working. When I remove this code, it does.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem. I ended up working around it with

```
var scriptor = new MigratorScriptingDecorator(dbMigrator);
var script = scriptor.ScriptUpdate(sourceMigration: null, targetMigration: null);
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
{
    conn.Open();
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(script, conn))
    {
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```